# How to prove $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} u(z_0+re^{i\theta}) d\theta = u(z_0)$ for harmonic polynomial $u$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Suppose $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set, Let $z_0 \in U$ and $r>0$ and assume $\{ z : |z-z_0|\leq r\}\subseteq U$, and $u$ is a harmonic polynomial on $U$.  Then textbook says
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} u(z_0+re^{i\theta}) d\theta = u(z_0)
\end{align}
but i wonder how it holds.

Comment: That is the mean-value equality which is satisfied by *all* harmonic functions, not just by harmonic polynomials.

Comment: If you wanted to prove it yourself, an easy route is to show that it holds for $u(z)=(z-z_0)^n$ for all natural numbers $n$, and then use the linearity of integration to assert that it holds for all polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is the famous *mean-value equality for harmonic functions*, see for example the section "Properties of harmonic functions -> The mean value property" in the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function (it is formulated in the general n-dimensional case there!). Moreover, this result holds for *all* harmonic functions on $U$, not only for polynomials.
A very good reference on this topic is "Functions of One Complex Variable I" by J. Conway (published with Springer), see the *Mean Value Theorem* 1.4 on page 253 in chapter X on *Harmonic Functions* and the following pages. Another standard reference is "Complex Analysis" by Lars V. Ahlfors, section 4.6 on *Harmonic Functions*, see in particular Theorem 20 and following.